# Internal error during creation of App Engine via deployment manager

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create an App Engine service via Deployment Manager.

My **deployment-manager.yaml** file looks like below

```
imports:
- path: create-app-engine-std.py

resources:
- name: create-app-engine-std-app
  type: create-app-engine-std.py
  properties:
        name: app-engine-std-app
        appsId: projectId
        zip:
            sourceUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/some-bucket/xyz.zip
            filesCount: 2
        version: v1
        runtime: nodejs8
```

My **create-app-engine-std.py** look like below

```
def GenerateConfig(cxt):
    deployment = {}
    if cxt.properties['zip']:
        deployment = {
            'zip': {
                'sourceUrl': cxt.properties['zip']['sourceUrl'],
                'filesCount': cxt.properties['zip']['filesCount']
            }
        }

    resources = [{
        'type': 'gcp-types/appengine-v1:apps.services.versions',
        'name': 'app-engine-std-app',
        'properties': {
            'servicesId': 'app-engine-std-test-app',
            'appsId': cxt.properties['appsId'],
            'deployment': deployment,
            'runtime': cxt.properties['runtime'],
            'threadsafe': True,
            'id': cxt.properties['version']
        }
    }]
    return {'resources': resources}
```

When I execute the deployment command I get following error

```
message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/appengine-v1:apps.services.versions","ResourceErrorCode":"500","ResourceErrorMessage":"An
    internal error occurred."}'
```

I tried using the [apps.services.versions.create](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/create) API but I always get following error although I am owner of the project

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Can someone guide me why I am getting the internal error and why can't I use the API. Thanks...

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @tomphp no. Google Cloud Platform support seems to be terrible on stackoverflow

Comment: What happens if you try to create the same service directly through the API instead of using deployment manager?